# PHP APC doesn't want store

Tags: php, caching, apc

I was install APC on my web server and find some problem...
Not all requests APC is store in memory. Over 30% requests to cache (apc_store) not working...
Why it happens and how i can do ideal caching??

Sorry my bad english. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are trying to cache more data than APC can store. By default APC only stores up to 30MB of data, any additional data is causes old data in the cache to be removed to make room for the new data.

You can increase the size of the APC cache in the `apc.ini` file. However, I recommend that you upgrade to a larger caching system such as memcached which will also support more servers as you grow.

Search for the [APC.php file that came with APC/PHP](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apc-php-cache-information/)

```
$ cd /; find -name apc.php | grep apc
```

Comment: No, i tested that. He store only 30% of requests.

Comment: @user1235098, if you run the apc.php file that comes with APC you can see a graph of how many "misses" there are and what data is currently cached. Remember, 30% of all requests means nothing. I could fill APC with just 1 request. APC caches the files as well as the data you are trying to cache in it. If you use wordpress that takes several megabytes just for system files.

Comment: I need 100% caching. How i can do that?

Comment: @user1235098 You need to do what I said above. Find and run the `apc.php` file. It will tell you what you need to solve your problem.